# How to End a "group call" in Sinch

Tags: sinch

I'm basically following the tutorial on https://www.sinch.com/docs/video/javascript/#groupcalling.

I'm able to get things working, however I am unable to end the call.  Right now I have 2 browser tabs pretending to be different users joining the same group chat.  "onGroupLocalMediaAdded" and "onGroupRemoteCallAdded" do get called, and I can display things fine.  But I can't figure out how a user can leave the group chat and ultimately trigger a call to "onGroupRemoteCallRemoved"

The Call class has a "hangup" method, but GroupCall does not.

any ideas?

Comment: Hey, use callconference instead, much more scalable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  Group Calling is really peer to peer calling.  So hanging up means iterating through each call object you received from a peer and calling hangup.

My terminate connection function now contains:

```
this.remoteCallsMap.forEach( (call) => {
    call.hangup();
});
```

I'm going to play around with call conference as mentioned in the other responses, but figured I'd post the answer in case anyone else plays around with call group and can't figure out how to end the call.

Answer (score 0):

Use call conference, it will be with a media server, callgroup will try to set up media to each client and will most likely impact your callquality.
 http://download.sinch.com.s3.amazonaws.com/docs/javascript/latest/reference/classes/CallClient.html#method_callConference

Comment: The documentation says call conference is voice only, is that true?  My desire is to add video collaboration to an existing tool.